# Showing $P_{n+1}(x)=x^2(P_n(x)-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}P_n(x))$ where $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

> Consider a function $f(t)=\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)$, $t>0$. For each positive integer $n$, let $P_n$ be the polynomial such that$$
> \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n}f(t)=P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right). \quad \forall t>0
> $$

Well to start with this is a long problem, I have seen that for $n=1$. it holds that$$
P_{n+1}(x)=x^2\left(P_n(x)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}P_n(x)\right).
$$

Now I wanted to prove this using induction.

Assume that for $n=m$, this is true. Thus

$$P_{m+1}(x)=x^2\left(P_m(x)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}P_m(x)\right).
$$

Now we are required to prove that:

$$P_{m+2}(x)=x^2\left(P_{m+1}(x)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}P_{m+1}(x)\right).$$

While trying to simplify the above expression, I found that$$
P_{m+2}(x)=x^2\left(\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}P_m(x)\right)(x^2-2x+1)+P_m(x)\cdot (x^2-2x)+x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}P_m(x)\right).
$$

But I am stuck with this $P_m(x)$. How do I get a substantial polynomial to start working with.

Also while finding $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n}f(t)$, I get no pattern! I tried it by putting $t=\dfrac{1}{z}$ but that was a stupid decision anyway!

**Solution:**

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\cdot (\dfrac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t))=\dfrac{d}{dt} (P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}})=e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}}{t^2}  $

$\implies \dfrac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}}f(t)=e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}}{t^2}$

$\implies P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}=e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(t)+P_n(t)\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}}{t^2}$

Cancelling $e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}} $ from both sides, we get,

$\implies P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})=\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{1}{t^2}$

$P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})=\dfrac{d}{d(\dfrac{1}{t})}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{1}{(\dfrac{1}{t})^2}$

Again $\dfrac{d}{d(\dfrac{1}{t})}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})=-t^2\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})$

$\implies P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})=t^2 P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})-t^2\dfrac{d}{dt} P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})$

$\implies P_{n+1}(t)=t^2 P_n(t)-t^2\dfrac{d}{dt} P_n(t)$

Hence proved.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $P_{n+1}(1/t)e^{-1/t}=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(P_n(1/t)e^{-1/t})=(\frac{d}{dx}P_n)(1/t)(-1/t^2)e^{-1/t}+(1/t^2)P_n(1/t)e^{-1/t}$. Therefore, $P_{n+1}(1/t)=(\frac{d}{dx}P_n)(1/t)(-1/t^2)+(1/t^2)P_n(1/t)$. Replacing $t=1/x$ you get the recurrence you want.

Comment: However, one readily verifies that the recursion implies $\deg P_{n+1}=\deg P_n+2\ne \deg P_n+1$, So $\deg P_n=n$ cannot nold for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an explicit formula note that
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}(-x)^{n+k}.$$
The above formula verifies the given recurrence
$$\begin{align}x^2\left(P_n(x)-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}P_n(x)\right)&=
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}(-x)^{n+k+2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}(n+k)(-x)^{n+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-2)!}(-x)^{n+1+k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!}(n+k)(-x)^{n+1+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}(-x)^{n+1+k}=P_{n+1}(x).\end{align}$$

Comment: Please see my OP.I have accidentally proved it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

$\dfrac{d}{dt}\cdot (\dfrac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t))=\dfrac{d}{dt} (P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}})=e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}}{t^2}  $

$\implies \dfrac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}}f(t)=e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}}{t^2}$

$\implies P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}=e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(t)+P_n(t)\cdot \dfrac{e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}}}{t^2}$

Cancelling $e^{-\dfrac{1}{t}} $ from both sides, we get,

$\implies P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})=\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{1}{t^2}$

$P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})=\dfrac{d}{d(\dfrac{1}{t})}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})+P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})\cdot \dfrac{1}{(\dfrac{1}{t})^2}$

Again $\dfrac{d}{d(\dfrac{1}{t})}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})=-t^2\dfrac{d}{dt}P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})$

$\implies P_{n+1}(\dfrac{1}{t})=t^2 P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})-t^2\dfrac{d}{dt} P_n(\dfrac{1}{t})$

$\implies P_{n+1}(t)=t^2 P_n(t)-t^2\dfrac{d}{dt} P_n(t)$

Hence proved.